# How to make web based code editor

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to create a code snippet website, all i need left is a nice looking open source code editor with syntax highlighting. I found http://ace.c9.io/ but it seems to not work when i pass PHP through the editor script;

PHP code being ran through CodeEditor:

```
    <div id="editor"><?php echo 'test'; ?></div>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
    editor.setReadOnly(true);
</script>
```

It shows 'test' in the editor box.

If i use this code to pass through Javascript it works:

```
<div id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}</div>


<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
```

I need one that easily allows me to enter any text/code and it highlight it appropriately.

Comment: codemirror can do php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encode `<` and `>` characters so they're not interpreted as HTML tags

```
<div id="editor">&lt;?php echo 'test'; ?&gt;</div>
```

If you're creating the page using PHP, you can use `htmlentities()` to perform this encoding. If you use jQuery, `$("#editor").text(code)` will encode it properly (using `.html()` will interpret the HTML tags).

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on .php file it will show test in editor box.
You must html encode to escape it.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars('<?php echo \'test\'; ?>'); ?>
```

Comment: Presumably the PHP to be shown in the editor won't be hardcoded...so I don't get this answer.